# Checking time interval in java

Tags: java, android, calendar

I want some Java code that will tell me when school is open based on the current time.

When I call this method between 9AM and 6PM it should return "school is open", otherwise it should return "school is closed" after 6 pm and before 9 am.

```
public Calendar shopStartTime(String msg)
{
    Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar schoolTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar schoolClosedTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    schoolTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
    schoolTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    schoolTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    schoolTime.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    schoolClosedTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
    schoolClosedTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    schoolClosedTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    schoolClosedTime.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    if (schoolTime.compareTo(currentTime) <= 0 && 
       (currentTime.compareTo(schoolClosedTime)>=0))
    {
        // check for time
        Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), "school is closed ", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else 
    {
        Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), " school is open", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return currentTime;
}
```

But the code is not working because it always returns the same result.  How do I test if one time is between two other time of days?

Comment: Shouldn't it read: " ... && currentTime.compareTo(schoolClosedTime)<=0)"? (Lesser than, not greater than)

Comment: I tried both way, its same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the javadocs!

```
if (currentTime.after(schoolTime) && currentTime.before(schoolClosedTime)) {
    // school is open
} else {
    // school is closed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check if hour <9 && hour >18:
(or something else)

```
Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour  = currentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

you only need ONE calendar

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `Calendar` that you have used , another simple approach would be :

```
private boolean inRange(Date now) throws ParseException {
    final Date start = new SimpleDateFormat("HH.mm.ss").parse("09.00.00");
    final Date end = new SimpleDateFormat("HH.mm.ss").parse("18.00.00");
    return now.after(start)&& now.before(end);
}
```

You can use `before()` and `after()` of [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) as well .